# Docker run changes the permission of the folder on the host machine

Tags: docker, file-permissions, workspace, docker-volume

I have a path in my host /Users/bhav/workspace. I am the owner of it as well.

I run docker command as follows (as root user)

```
docker run -t -d -u root -w /Users/bhav/workspace -v /Users/bhav/workspace:/Users/bhav/workspacerw,z -v /Users/bhav/workspace@tmp:/Users/bhav/workspace@tmp:rw,z 7ff0d5f7b0ce
```

After i exit my container,

the permission of my **workspace** folder has changed to '**root**'.

How to avoid/rectify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `-u root` in your `docker run`, you are telling the container to run as root.

Instead, try `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)` to have the container run as your user.

Unfortunately this might not work if your image is not setup to run as different users, but often it will work (and if it's your own image, you can adjust things accordingly).

Longer version: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/containers-filesystem-data-processing/